# Difference of coding in vb.net and C# issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, class, object

Guys I am working with an API integration project in vb.net. Result from API is returned in XML format and I have been provided with some some of the classes which help me to navigate through xml. It's one of the class is `WSGetFareQuoteRequest` which has many properties. And one of its properties is `Result` which is defined in the integration document as:

Response Description

Structure of `WSGetFareQuoteResponse` is as follows:

```
Field Name                      DataType                       Remarks 
Result*                         WSResult                       This        result       will 
                                                                comprise   of   the   new 
                                                                fare(if      any    of    the 
                                                                component        of      fare 
                                                               gets               updated), 
                                                               otherwise         it     will 
                                                                remain the same. 

Status                          WSStatus                        It will be having the 
                                                                status         or      error 
                                                                information.
```

When I asked API team regarding the initialisation of this result property of this object they provided me c# code as shown below :

```
WSGetFareQuoteRequest wsFareQuoteRequest = new WSGetFareQuoteRequest();

WSGetFareQuoteResponse wsFareQuoteResponse = new WSGetFareQuoteResponse();

int nor = 1;

if (searchResponse.Result != null && searchResponse.Result.Length    0 && 
   objResult[i].IsLcc)

   {

   wsFareQuoteRequest.Result = new WSResult[nor];

   wsFareQuoteRequest.Result[0] = new WSResult();

   wsFareQuoteRequest.Result[0] = objResult[i];

   wsFareQuoteRequest.SessionId = searchResponse.SessionId;

   wsFareQuoteResponse = bApi.GetFareQuote(wsFareQuoteRequest);
```

Now my question is that I am doing the project in vb.net.I tried its vb.net equivalent it is showing me error at first line of object creation of Result property.I tried its vb.net equivalent as:

```
wsFareQuoteRequest.Result = New WSResult(nor) 
'Only above line is creating error as Too many arguments to Pub Sub New'
            wsFareQuoteRequest.Result(0) = New WSResult()
            wsFareQuoteRequest.Result(0) = searchresponse.Result(i)
            wsFareQuoteRequest.SessionId = searchresponse.SessionId
            wsFareQuoteResponse = bapi.GetFareQuote(wsFareQuoteRequest)
```

Comment: last piece of code is vb.net equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arrays in Visual Basic > Creating an Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_CreatingAnArray)

```
cargoWeights = New Double(10) {}
atmospherePressures = New Short(2, 2, 4, 10) {}
inquiriesByYearMonthDay = New Byte(20)()() {}
```

and in your case it would be:

```
wsFareQuoteRequest.Result = New WSResult(nor) {}
```

you are missing the `{}` at the end.

Comment: Thankyou @t3chbot..I was stuck on this from last 3 days. :)